# What is the benefit of using the covector formulation to avoid metrics when speaking of integrals?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading a book called geometry of physics by Frankel. In page  xxxvii, the covector formulation of the line integral is given:

$$ \int_C \alpha = \int_C \alpha(x_i) dx_i$$

To evaluate the above expression , we parameterize the $dx_i$ in terms of some variable $t$ and the sort of parameterization determines our curve. This procedure is known as pull back.

Cool, now this allows us to avoid inner products when defining line integrals... but what is the point? What could have done the same by defining a vector field and a metric. My question is: Why is it profitable to avoid defining a metric when dealing with integrals?

Comment: Probably that "Integrals of differential $k$-forms over $k$-chains depend only on the smooth structure, so their realm of applicability is larger than the setting of Riemannian geometry".

Comment: Vector field and a matrix?

Comment: I meant metric, thanks again for catching the typo @TedShifrin

Comment: So, to emphasize what @AndrewD.Hwang said, it is most natural to integrate differential forms. To convert to vector fields (which you can’t do in all dimensions other than for curves and hypersurfaces) requires the metric. You might check out some of my YouTube lectures on forms, integrals, and Stokes’s Thm.